# Glassfish v3.1 - Trying to deploying a simple Jersey rest service - Cannot Deploy

Tags: eclipse, rest, jersey, glassfish-3

I am trying to deploy a simple rest service with eclipse (using jersey) on glassfish. 
I got the

> Publishing to glassfish 3.1 at localhost... has encoutered a problem
>   Cannot Deploy sample: Deployment Error for module: sample: " error when i ''run on server''

In the glassfish logs, there is only the following error :

> [SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;| Invalid option: keepstate|#]

My web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jax-rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My sample.java

```
package M2R;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("converter")
public class sample {

  @GET @Path("{myparam}")
  @Produces("text/html")
  public String getHtml(@PathParam("myparam") String myparam) {
      return "<html><body>"+myparam+"</body></html>";
  }
}
```

Does one have an idea ??
Why does the deployment failed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a deployment issue more than a packaging or code problem.
Can you undeploy and deploy again? The "keepstate" option of "asadmin deploy" seems to be a problem (maybe an issue with the combination of Eclipse+Plugin you're using).

You should really be using the more recent GlassFish 3.1.1 btw.

Comment: I change for Glassfish 3.1.1 but it still doesn't work : I got the message : > cannot Deploy LinkedService
Deployment Error for module: LinkedService: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: I have the same problem. Why did you choose this as an answer if it doesn't work?

Comment: After many hours of hacking and manipulations, it's finally worked